# Consume API with php and cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

Hi I'm trying to consume an API.

I need to add the API key in the header
API endpoint = http://overheid.io/api/kvk

if you want to test things, you can create an account here: https://overheid.io/auth/register
Documentation is in Dutch and can be found here: https://overheid.io/documentatie/kvk

This is what I came up with but do not get passed authentication.

```
<?php 
$service_url = 'https://overheid.io/api/kvk';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER => true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "ovio-api-key:the_api_key");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $curl_response;   
?>
```

Edit: I've replaced the initial code part, with the solutions, but still no success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code has several typographical errors, like missing closing ) on two lines.

Comment: this api uses https did you use curl with ssl certificates because by default curl do not trust that, use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: @Jessica, thnx, I've added them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option to pass the Authentication header. You also seemed to have some syntax errors.

```
<?php 
$service_url = 'https://overheid.io/api/kvk';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ovio-api-key:the_api_key");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $curl_response;
```

But, this API seem to use a custom header...so you can try the following if it the above does not work:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("ovio-api-key: yourkey"));
```

UPDATE:

I used the following with an account I created on their site:

```
<?php
$service_url = 'https://overheid.io/api/kvk';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("ovio-api-key: key"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $curl_response;
```

This worked for me when I replaced the "key" part with the 64 character key they provide.

Comment: I tried both, but stll the same error:

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Server: nginx/1.8.0 Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: HHVM/3.7.3 Vary: Accept-Encoding Set-Cookie: xxx; expires=Sun, 26-Jul-2015 16:40:53 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/ Set-Cookie: laravel_session=yyy; expires=Sun, 26-Jul-2015 16:40:53 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Sun, 26 Jul 2015 14:40:53 GMT {"error":"No valid API key in the request. for more info check https:\/\/overheid.io\/documentatie"}

Comment: You tried with a space after `:` ? A lot of examples show it with a space after it. Including the documentation they link to.

Comment: @Jessica, Thanx for the suggestion, I've added a space after it, but it didn't made any difference.

Comment: See my update, the example worked for me. I also made a mistake previously by using the variable `$ch` and not `$curl`

Comment: @Chris, I still keep on getting "No valid API key in the request." error.
I tried it in IE/FF and Chrome.
I copied the whole sample, and only replaced the apikey
Could this be a cURL problem on my server?
Can you pm me your API Key?

Comment: Try with this key: 481afd99f5ecc1c6d2ec3e8ac091bd4730ae26cce790afd4482684530e93047e

I will revoke the key later.

Comment: @Chris, That one works, I've created 3 key's allready, and no luck.
I'll make a new account and see what happens.

Comment: If it helps, this is the link I used to create a key: https://overheid.io/profile/api-keys/create

Comment: @Chris, with a new account it works, so no idea why with the Original account it didn't work.
The account was made with a Hotmail account, mayby they do not accept these kind of email addresses...

Thank you for your help